# Zero Function Linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is $f: \mathbb{R^m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ defined by $f(\vec x) \equiv 0 $ considered a linear map? If the definition for linear map is one that satisfies additivity and homogeneity, then $f$ obviously is a linear map. But I'd to confirm $f$ is not specifically excluded in the usual definitions of linear mappings.

Comment: The set of linear maps form a vector space, and you've found the element "$0$".

Comment: @Nicolas I see! The set of constant functions also form a vector space, and the zero function is also the "0" element in this space. What's interesting, I think, is that this zero function is the only constant function that is a linear map.

Comment: No, it is no exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the zero function is indeed a linear map.

Any function that is additive and homogeneous is a linear map by definition, and in your case:

- $f(x+y) = 0 = 0+0 = f(x) + f(y)$
- $f(\alpha x) = 0 = \alpha \cdot 0 = \alpha f(x)$

So $f$ is both homogeneous and additive.

In fact, as one commenter pointed out, you can define addition and multiplication with constant to the set of all linear functions.

- $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$
- $(\alpha\cdot f)(x) = \alpha \cdot (f(x))$

These two definitions are well defined and map linear functions to linear functions.

Using these two operations, the set of all linear functions from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$ is a linear space (which, by the way, is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{m\cdot n}$) and is more commonly viewed as the space of all $n\times m$ matrices) and the zero function is the zero element.

Comment: Thanks! Is what I said in my comment under the question also correct? Just wanted to check.

Comment: @FreshAir It is correct, the space of constant functions is also a vector space (using the same operations as in my answer, even!), albeit much less interesting. It is isomorphic simply to $\mathbb R^n$. Also, yes, the only function that is both constant and linear is the zero function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n, x \mapsto 0$ is a linear map.

Linearity: 
$$
f(\lambda x + \mu y) = 0 = \lambda 0 + \mu 0 = \lambda f(x) + \mu f(y)
$$ 
for arbitrary $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

The linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be represented as $n \times m$ matrices, with $0$ having all entries $0$.

Comment: Thank @mvw - this definitely adds to the discussion. As 5xum's answer came first I decided to accept that answer.